# Is there any method to solve the many particle stationary scattering problem like the one for the single particle problem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-information

The stationary scattering problem by a potential barrier lies in every textbook of quantum mechanics, in which the scattering amplitudes for the single particle wave can be obtained by solving the boundary conditions. I wonder is there any similar method for the many particle wave functions scattered by a potential by solving the boundary conditions? For the many particle scattering problem, the scattering amplitudes should describe the scattering between different many particle states. Let me make this question nontrivial by restricting that the many particle wave function should not be direct product states, or they are entangled.

Comment: I guess you aren't looking for the answer *"That's what QFT is for"*?

Comment: A common approach in a *dilute* many-body system is to consider only binary scattering processes. If you are happy to make this reduction, I think the procedure you envision would reduce to the usual two-body scattering problem in any case, since only one pair of coordinates participate in a given scattering event (I'm assuming you are interested in systems of mainly indistinguishable particles).

Comment: I do not focus on the QFT here but on the scattering process described by the wave function. I have also revised my question that I here talk about the many particle wave function scattered by the barrier potential, actually not the scattering between the particles themselves.